# S3 bucket starts downloading an image instead of opening it

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this line of code

```
self.s3.put_object(Body=base64.b64decode(base64_image.split(',')[1]), Bucket='name-of-bucket', Key=filename + '.png', ContentType='image/png')
```

servicing for uploading an image to an s3 bucket, I receive the image in base64 format from the FE part of my project. So the issue is that I cannot just open the image from the s3 bucket in the browser it wants to download it to my computer.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Can you please explain?

Comment: The problem is that I want to open the image straight in the browser instead of downloading it.

Comment: S3 buckets can contain _any_ type of data. Binary, text, images, movies, whatever. So there is no way to "open it in the browser," since browsers may not be able to interpret the data. Downloading is the only sane option. You can download it, and then open it with your local browser, if it supports viewing PNG files.

Comment: That's not true, when you upload a image to a bucket an url is generated, if you visit given url the image should open in the browser. If I upload given image manually through the aws site and I visit that url the image opens in the browser, but when I upload it through my python script visiting the generated url just wants to download it instead of just opening it.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly well for me, and set the ContentType on the object. When went to open the file, it opened within the browser.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that's strange, for me it always wants to download the file, but I tested the URL with <img> tag and it opens it on my FE project. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It might be a setting in your browser. Try using a different browser, or even a different computer (eg launch a fresh EC2 Windows instance and try from there).